# Sending multiple SOAP requests in one packet

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am using the aonaware.com dictionary web service for my application.

I need to send dozens of requests for word definitions, but that takes too long by sending them independently.

How can I send multiple SOAP requests at once (in one packet)?

I am using java and the service's WSDL file is located here:

http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`How can I send multiple SOAP requests at once (in one packet)?`
What do you mean `packet`? TCP packet? You can't.
SOAP is carried over HTTP which is a request/response protocol.
That means each SOAP request is carried over a different POST request.

What you could do is send multiple requests concurrently which means over different connections.
That will be faster than sending them serially but takes resources and bandwidth.

You could also check if the underlying connection is closed after the response. If it does for some reason make it persistent so that you don't re-open the TCP connections and avoid that overhead

Comment: Is there another querying protocol which allows for many requests at once?

Comment: In theory SOAP web services are transport independent (you can use JMS, even SMTP). But this web service is using HTTP transport so you need to cope with that.

Comment: @PiotrKochanski:In theory you can send SOAP over plain TCP as well.